# Join 2 tables - fill in missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join, inner-join

I am having trouble joining 2 tables and filtering the data precisely. I can slightly modify the tables if need be. I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

```
Table A
System_Code | Name         | Client ID| Fund   | Purchase_Date  | Shares
1           | Lily         | 123456   | 001    | 02/21/2016     | 100
1           | Lily         | 123456   | 001    | 02/26/2016     | 200
2           | Lily         | 123456   | 002    | 02/24/2016     | 250
```

and so on

Each fund has their own System_Code

```
Table B
System_Code |  Date           | Price
1           |  02/21/2016     | 10
1           |  02/22/2016     | 10 
1           |  02/23/2016     | 9
1           |  02/24/2016     | 10
1           |  02/25/2016     | 11
1           |  02/26/2016     | 10.5
```

and so on

My goal is to find out how much share a client holds on a particular day and the price per share.

If I simply join 2 tables ON (tableA.System_Code = tableB.System_Code), I get this:

```
System_Code| Name | Client ID| Fund |Purchase_Date|Shares| Date     | Price 
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/21/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/26/2016   |200   |02/26/2016| 10.5
```

If I join 2 tables together WHERE tableB.Date >= tableA.Purchase

```
System_Code| Name | Client ID| Fund |Purchase_Date|Shares| Date     | Price 
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/21/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/22/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/23/2016| 9
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/24/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/25/2016| 11
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/26/2016| 10.5
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/26/2016   |200   |02/26/2016| 10.5
```

As you can see, it's almost perfect except the last 2 rows

```
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/26/2016| 10.5
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/26/2016   |200   |02/26/2016| 10.5
```

Since there is a purchase made on 02/26/2016, the first row with a purchase date of 02/21/2016 should drop. The desired result would be:

```
System_Code| Name | Client ID| Fund |Purchase_Date|Shares| Date     | Price 
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/21/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/22/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/23/2016| 9
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/24/2016| 10
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/21/2016   |100   |02/25/2016| 11
1          | Lily | 123456   | 001  |02/26/2016   |200   |02/26/2016| 10.5
```

Hope I am conveying my points clearly. TIA!

Comment: You are making your points very clear! Can you make a sqlFiddle with test data?

Answer (score 0):

Your final query should look something like that:

```
select *
 from A
  left join B
  on (A.System_Code = B.System_Code)
 where B.Date >= A.Purchase
```

Comment: That would not work. As stated in the question, it creates duplicate entries if I simply specify where B.Date >= A.Purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
    ,b.*
FROM dbo.Table_A a
JOIN table_b b ON b.System_Code = a.System_Code
WHERE b.DATE >= a.Purchase_Date

EXCEPT

SELECT a.System_Code
    ,a.NAME
    ,a.Client_ID
    ,a.Fund
    ,a.Purchase_Date
    ,a.Shares
    ,b.System_Code
    ,a2.Purchase_Date AS DATE
    ,b.Price
FROM dbo.Table_A a
JOIN TABLE_a a2 ON a.System_Code = a2.System_Code
    AND a.Purchase_Date < a2.Purchase_Date
JOIN table_b b ON b.System_Code = a.System_Code
```